# Continuity in Topological Space vs Metric Space

Tags: general-topology, analysis

In *Introduction to General Topology*, by Cain, I find the following Example: 3.10:

"For the set of real numbers, the pseudometric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ generates the usual topology. So for a real valued function $f$ defined on the set of real numbers, continuity with respect to the usual topology on both the domain and the range is equivalent to the tradition $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of elementary calculus."

I do not understand the logic of how Cain gets from the first sentence to the next. What does generating the usual topology have to do with using the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of continuity?

I think the example is referencing the theorem below.

Theorem 3.9: Suppose $f:(X,d)\rightarrow(Y,\rho)$
  is a function from one pseudometric space into another. Then $f$
  is continuous iff it is true that $\forall x\in X,\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0$
  such that $d(x,y)<\delta\implies\rho(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon$.

Thus the example makes it sound like if $f$ is a function from R to R with the usual topology on both, we can use $\epsilon - \delta$ definition, however the theorem (which might seem to justify this) only applies to a function between pseudo-metric spaces. Thus I am confused.

Comment: Is he saying that a function is continuous in the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ sense if and only if the inverse image of open sets is open? In other words the metric space definition coincides with the topological one.

Comment: Once you've shown that $|x-y|$ is a pseudometric (in fact, a metric),on $R$ generating the usual  topology (i.e., the same open sets), then a map from $R$ to $R$ _is_ a map from one pseudometric space to another (although in this case, the "another" happens to be the same). Thus, you can apply the stated theorem.

Comment: @quasi I think I understand now. The theorem didn't make it explicit between which topologies f was continuous. It should state:

"Suppose $f:(X,d)\rightarrow(Y,\rho)$
  is a function from one pseudometric space into another. Let $\mathbf{T},\mathbf{S}$
  be the topologies generated by the pseudometrics $d,\rho$. 

Then f
  is continuous from $(X,\mathbf{T})\rightarrow(Y,\mathbf{S})$
  iff it is true that $\forall x\in X,\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0$
  such that $d(x,y)<\delta\implies\rho(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon$
 ."

Thus, letting $d,\rho$ = |x|, and $X,Y$=R, we get the example.